# Complex request routing in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, routing, proxy, amazon-route53

My goal is to be able to route traffic from Route53 to my autoscaling group using relatively complex rules. Like:

- 1% of traffic with this value in the url path should be routed to ASG A
- 0.1% of traffic with this value in the body should be routed to ASG B
- Rest should go to ASG C

What is the best solution for me considering that I want to be able to change the rules quickly and need to have programmatical access to them?

Comment: You can't look at body content with Route53, as far as I know. Maybe Lambda Edge could help? Otherwise you're going to have to set up something much heavier, such as decoding the request in PHP and acting on it. I don't even think HAProxy / Nginx does that. Why do you need to do something so unusual?

Comment: The main reason is to be able to run experiments for specific clients. I want to be able to deploy a new feature to production, test it on a specific audience and only then make it generally available. For some clients, I will be able to use query parameters but for some, I will need to scan the request body.

Comment: I suspect you're going to have to write code to achieve to achieve your aims in this way. I suggest instead that you create another question that gives more background on what you're trying to achieve, and let the community guide you towards a way to achieve this that is simpler and don't involve a heck of a lot of work. Experiments with a percentage of people / traffic is a solved problem.

Comment: Thanks @Tim. It should be a solved problem but I didn't find any solutions. Created new question https://serverfault.com/questions/944267/running-experiments-in-aws

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running experiments for limited audience in AWS](https://serverfault.com/questions/944267/running-experiments-for-limited-audience-in-aws)